# Confusion on how the bundler's group works

Tags: ruby, bundler

I'm using ruby 1.9.3p194 and bundler 1.1.4

In my Gemfile I have this:

```
group :production do
   gem 'thin', '1.4.1'
end
```

When I run $ rails s, bundler keeps complains:

```
Could not find gem 'thin (>= 1.4.1) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I'm running under development environment, so shouldn't it NOT care if it is installed or not? Dose bundler force you to install ALL the gems when running $ rails s?

I also tried the group:test, same thing happens.  That doesn't really make sense to me, can anyone help?

### my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.6'
gem 'mysql2'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

group :production do
  gem 'thin', '1.4.1'
end

gem 'devise', '2.1.2'
gem 'cancan', '1.6.8'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.3'
```

Comment: What does the rest of your Gemfile look like? And specifically, in what group can rspec be found?

Comment: Run bundle install like it said. And read the documentation http://gembundler.com/rationale.html

Comment: @Vincent B: thanks for comment. I take another look at the doc again, it does mention IF I call $ bundle install --without production, bundler will add a flag in its config and ignore the gems in group when require "bundler/setup" -- I guess my question is  more like: IF I never set the flag (only called $ bundle install without any oprion) does it makes gemfile's group totally useless?? because when I do $ rails s, it just requires all the gems, disregard which group gems' at

Comment: @Confusion: sorry i made a typo - it should be missing gem 'thin' not 'rspec', thanks for comment

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the problem is that you are running `rails s`, while you need to run `bundle exec rails s`. If you precede a command with `bundle exec`, it is executed within the context of the bundle. All the gems available to bundler are then available to the command.

By default, gems from bundles are installed in the global gem directory. This can produce confusing results when you don't prepend `bundle exec` to a command: imagine you have both rails 3.1 and rails 3.2 in your global gems and your Gemfile mentions 3.1. Then you will still call the executable from rails 3.2 when you simply say `rails` on the command line.

Now of course `thin` could only be missing if it wasn't installed with the global gems. Assuming you've used the `--path` option to bundler at least once, your gems have been installed to the path specified there and not to the global repository. After using `--path`, you *must* specify `bundle exec`, otherwise gems simply won't be found at all.